# Проблема с записью в файл

Tags: java, файлы

Здравствуйте уважаемые участники форума. Подскажите пожалуйста: в чем проблема. Мне нужно что бы сервер принимал соединение от клиента. При этом все получаемые данные при новом подключениии сразу же записывал в текстовый файл. Клиент посылает данные в формате UTF-8. Сервер принимает. В консоль выводит. Вот только в файл ничего не пишется. Записывается только последняя  строка: stop. Остальное не пишется. Точнее видно, что размер файла меняется, но ничего не сохраняется.

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    int port = 9003;
    final ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    String line = null;
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Socket is wait");
        final Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection succesful");
        Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FileInput fi = new FileInput();
                try {
                    fi.FilePrinterStart(s);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
        thr.start();


    }



}
public class FileInput {
public void FilePrinterStart(Socket s) throws IOException{
    File f1 = new File("file1" + s.getLocalPort() + ".txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(fos);
    f1.canRead();
    f1.canWrite();
    System.out.println("File is create");
    System.out.println(f1.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("dis is create");
    String line = dis.readUTF();
    System.out.println(line);
    if(line.equals("stop")){
        s.close();
    }
    dout.writeUTF(line);
    dout.flush();
    fos.close();
    s.close();

    System.out.println(f1.getAbsoluteFile());


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)`, т.к тебе нужно дозапись в файл.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это сделать. Ни у FileOutputStream, ни у DataOutputStream метода append найти не могу. Не могли бы вы подсказать подподробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Все работает. Разобрался) Огромное Вам спасибо)